# AWS Cognito Lambda Error in AddPermission = PolicyLengthExceededException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS lambda and Cognito.

I am creating a user pool, app clients and configuring a trigger for post confirmation.

The user pool gets created, the app client creation is also successful.

When I try to call the API - `AddPermission`, I get an error.

> Error in AddPermission = PolicyLengthExceededException: The final
>   policy size (20593) is bigger than the limit (20480).

I am passing below parameters, as per the AWS documentation, to the function AddPermission-

```
Action
FunctionName
Principal
SourceArn
StatementId
```

I am not sure which of the policy size is causing this problem?

Any solution to this problem?

here is the code snippet.

```
actionString := "lambda:InvokeFunction"     
principalString := "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"  
sourceArn := userPoolArn    
statementIdString := "cognitoaddpermission" + customerId

addPermissionInput := &lambda.AddPermissionInput{
    Action:       aws.String(actionString),
    FunctionName: aws.String(lambdaFunctionName),
    Principal:    aws.String(principalString),
    SourceArn:    aws.String(sourceArn),
    StatementId:  aws.String(statementIdString),
}

resultAddPermission, errAddPermission := lambdaSessionClient.AddPermission(addPermissionInput)

if errAddPermission != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error in AddPermission = ", errAddPermission)
} else {
    fmt.Println("resultAddPermission successful,  ", resultAddPermission)
}
```

I came across one more link -
https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/48

Comment: can you share code for addpermission function so we can recrete the issue?

Comment: Here is the code -                                                                  
     addPermissionInput := &lambda.AddPermissionInput{
  Action:       aws.String(actionString),
  FunctionName: aws.String(lambdaFunctionName),
  Principal:    aws.String(principalString),
  SourceArn:    aws.String(sourceArn),
  StatementId:  aws.String(statementIdString),
 }

 resultAddPermission, errAddPermission := lambdaSessionClient.AddPermission(addPermissionInput)

Comment: please edit the question and add code there so it is more readable.